# Multisite Subdomain Using More Resources Than Others?

Tags: multisite, database, subdomains, domain, vps

I have a WordPress Multisite - `www.domain.com` and a subomdain `example.domain.com` on a performance VPS. The subdomain is getting way more traffic and using more resources, and we don't want it to slow down the other subdomains or the main website.

In order to provide resources to example.domain.com, would I be able to have it hosted on a separate VPS? I understand that all subdomains are connected to the same database; however, I've received lots of different answers and debates on this topic.

Yes, I will be upgrading to a dedicated server, but the subdomain is still using way more resources than the parent and others. What would be the best way to prevent the other sites from slowing down?

Should I copy the subdomain WP and create a separate WordPress installation on a subdomain. Then see how I can connect the WordPress to the other WordPress? that way it has its own installation and resources?

Comment: If your question has been answered, could you please accept the solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience... I would keep using Multisite for your setup for organizational purposes and ease of management.

**Here's a list of things you could try before emptying out the pockets:**

1. Consider caching options. (Personally, I like using
   [W3TC](https://wordpress.org/plugins/w3-total-cache/)), but there's
   many options for this.
2. Consider [Jetpack](https://wordpress.org/plugins/jetpack/) CDN for images. (I've had reasonable success with this.)
3. Consider tuning your Web Server, Database Server, and PHP
   Configuration according to your system specifications to get ideal
   performance.
4. Consider upgrading to PHP 7 (if not already on it) -- It's significantly faster than PHP 5.
5. Consider [PHP-FPM](https://php-fpm.org/)?
6. Consider [Hyper-DB](https://wordpress.org/plugins/hyperdb/)?

One of the biggest overlooked options of course is code and query optimization.

I could be wrong with my ideology here, but I would assume that if the server only had to load one set of files it would result in better performance versus loading two sets of files.

If it's clear as day that one site is completely hogging resources, and you've made every effort to optimize your setup. THEN perhaps at that point, it's time to move that site to it's own server.

Also, before you immediately jump to a dedicated machine, consider all the optimizations I mentioned above and beef your VPS resources. It might be cheaper to double your VPS resources than full blown dedicated machine.

Answer (score 0):

In order to provide resources to example.domain.com, would I be able to have it hosted on a separate VPS?

Answer is yes you can. By setting DNS to pointing to new VPS ip.

If you separate them. When you subdomain with heavy load down. Others still online. but if you put them in same VPS. If your VPS can't handle it will all down.